# Microsoft Access

Tags: access, oledb, mdb

впервые столкнулся с задачей сделать выборку из базы данных micorosoft access и как бы я не пытался к ней подключится, вижу вот это:

`Ошибка. (Не удается найти указанный поставщик. Вероятно, он установлен неправильно.)`

Connection String которые я пробовал:

`Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Access.mdb`

`Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Acccess.mdb`

И несмотря на то, что я скачивал с сайта MS некий `AccessDatabaseEngine.exe` и ставил все подряд, что советовали из гугла, ничего не помгло, та же ситуация и на MS Server.

Comment: Я просто вместе с лицензионным MSAccess сохранял файл как .mdb и в папку с `exe` заливал его. И без лишнего софта.

Comment: Так мне нужно из файла базы данных скриптом сделать необходимую выборку

Comment: Вы показывайте конкретный код, на конкретном ЯП (который неплохо бы указать тегом). Потому как сейчас вопрос "ниачём", а ConnectionString обе нормальные (ну если не считать того, что обычно Data Source фиксируют точкой с запятой, см. https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/)...

Comment: @Mamba сейчас о чём идет речь? Вы виборку сделать не можете? Вопрос не конкретную проблему описывает. Если подключить не можете, я просто указал как делаю я и никогда не сталкивался с проблемой. У вас файл mdb в папке с exe?

Comment: Да, в папке с exe, ЯП пробовал разные, и мне в принципе без разницы. Да и дело не в ЯП, проблема в этом самом Provider, которого "Не удается найти указанный поставщик"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исходя из ошибки, видно, что в ODBC отсутствует драйвер для баз Access.
А именно он нужен Вам для подключения к базе из стороннего кода.
Если отсутствует полнофункциональный Office, то установите Access Runtime - он должен установить и прописать драйвер в ODBC